# What is the default gap penalty using muscle in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm using the muscle package in R to align multiple sequences, and want to know what gap penalty the algorithm is applying (if any) when the argument "gapopen" is not included

```
c <- muscle::muscle(chroma)
```

The alignment looks fine, but I'd like to know how strictly/leniently gaps are being inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the muscle package is admittedly poor but at least it refers us to the online documentation of the muscle software. There we find a footnote regarding the default value of the `gapopen` (and other) parameters:

> Default depends on the profile scoring function. To determine the default, use `–verbose –log` and check the log file.

So, to determine the default given your scoring function, rerun the function and pass `verbose = TRUE, log = TRUE`, and check the log file output.

Comment: Hi Konrad, thanks, much appreciated. From the log file, looks like it's really stringent by default: Gap open                 -400